# node.js child_process#spawn bypass stdin/stdout inner buffers

Tags: node.js, buffer, spawn

I'm using `child_process#spawn` to use external binaries through node.js. Each binary search for precise words in a string, depending on a language, and produce an output depending on an input text. They don't have inner buffers. usage examples :

- `echo "I'm a random input" | ./my-english-binary`
  produces text like `The word X is in the sentence`
- `cat /dev/urandom | ./my-english-binary` produces infinite ouptut

I want to use each of these binaries as "server". I want to launch a new  binary instance after a language never found before is met, send data to it with stdin.write() when necessary, and get its output directly with stdout.on('data') event. The problem is that stdout.on('data') isn't called before a huge amount of data is sent to stdin.write(). stdout or stdin (or both) might have inner blocking buffers... But I want the output as soon as possible because otherwise, the program might wait hours before new input showed up and unlock stdin.write() or stdout.on('data'). How can I change their inner buffer size ? Or maybe can I use another non-blocking system ?

My code is:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const path = require('path');

class Driver {

  constructor() {
    // I have one binary per language
    this.instances = {
      frFR: {
        instance: null,
        path: path.join(__dirname, './my-french-binary')
      },
      enGB: {
        instance: null,
        path: path.join(__dirname, './my-english-binary')
      }
    }
  };

  // this function just check if an instance is running for a language
  isRunning(lang) {
    if (this.instances[lang] === undefined)
      throw new Error("Language not supported by TreeTagger: " + lang);
    return this.instances[lang].instance !== null;
  }

  // launch a binary according to a language and attach the function 'onData' to the stdout.on('data') event
  run(lang, onData) {
    const instance = spawn(this.instances[lang].path,{cwd:__dirname});
    instance.stdout.on('data', buf => onData(buf.toString()));
    // if a binary instance is killed, it will be relaunched later
    instance.on('close', () => this.instances[lang].instance = null );
    this.instances[lang].instance = instance;
  }

  /**
   * indefinitely write to instance.stdin()
   * I want to avoid this behavior by just writing one time to stdin
   * But if I write only one time, stdout.on('data') is never called
   * Everything works if I use stdin.end() but I don't want to use it
   */
  write(lang, text) {
    const id = setInterval(() => {
      console.log('setInterval');
      this.instances[lang].instance.stdin.write(text + '\n');
    }, 1000);
  }

};

// simple usage example
const driver = new Driver;
const txt = "This is a random input.";

if (driver.isRunning('enGB') === true)
  driver.write('enGB', txt);
else {
  /** 
   * the arrow function is called once every N stdin.write()
   * While I want it to be called after each write
   */
  driver.run('enGB', data => console.log('Data received!', data));
  driver.write('enGB', txt);
}
```

I tried to:

- use cork() and uncork() around stdin.write().
- pipe child_process.stdout() to a custom Readable and a Socket.
- Override the highWaterMark value to 1 and 0 in stdin, stdout and the aforementioned Readable
- Lots of other things I forgot...

Moreover, I can't use stdin.end() because I don't want to kill my binaries instances each time a new text arrives. Does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2985

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking back to this topic 7 years later, `cat /dev/urandom ...`
will always provide infinite output. If you wanted a specific number of bits you would need to use something like
`head -c 256 /dev/urandom > bytefilename.bytes` or `dd if=/dev/urandom count=1 bs=256 | sha256sum` (I used the latter example recently for an entropy example in a crypto project)